# how to create vertical menu with vertical font?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

- i try to create vertical menu show like in image but as you can see in design font also in vertical position so how can do this ?

  1. i want to create vertical menu using ul li , with vertical single font
  2. i try to rotate li tag but not set
  3. also i want to make this menu responsive menu

[image: i want to create like this type of menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li><span style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;">abcd</span></li>
    <li><span style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;">abcd</span></li>
    <li><span style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;">abcd</span></li>
    <li><span style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;">abcd</span></li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Try This and do responsive with media query

check also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation